# How to find the no of machines/IPaddress connected to same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, arp

I am connected to WiFi named: santosh in my home. I am looking for any command in unix or windows command prompt to check which all machines or IP address are connected to the same networks i.e. on SSID:santosh.

Suppose my IP address is  192.168.23.1. So I have ping to respective broadcast "ping -b 192.168.23.255" and then performed "arp -a" for output.

But things are not working properly and ping is also also not working properly.
kindly let me know whats wrong i have done or any other way to do this?

Comment: What operating system? "things are not working properly and ping is also also not working properly" Please [edit] and provide error message and explain what is not working.

Comment: You could also access the web admin interface of the router, perhaps with curl and grep or something like that to extract the needed data.

Comment: When i am broadcasting using ping -b xx.xx.xx.xx its not working.

Answer (score 0):

to know the number of systems are connected to your network, Go to run and type cmd and press enter. A command window will appear simply type arp -a and this  command will return a list of connected systems.

You can try another way 
Step 1: - Go to start and click on Control Panel.
Step 2: - Type Network in the search box and press enter.
Step 3: - Now click on View Network Computers and Devices.

it will list all systems connected to your network.

Comment: But the OP already mentioned that `arp -a` does not work for him?

Comment: ohh, sory its by mistake

Comment: i am trying to get the list in kali machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **host discovery** with nmap on Unix / Linux:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24
```

or

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24
```

This command makes a discovery that consists of an ICMP echo request, TCP SYN to port 443, TCP ACK to port 80, and an ICMP timestamp request by default.

If a firewall is blocking ICMP echo and ports 80 & 443 then it won't work.

One option is the `-P0` flag (or `-Pn` in newer versions) which performs a port scan on all the IP addresses. (This will take a large amount of time to complete the scan). The better option would be to specify custom ports for scanning. Nmap allows you to probe specific ports with SYN/UDP packets.

It is generally recommended to probe commonly used ports e.g. TCP-22 (ssh) or 135 ( Windows client/server communication) or  445 (Windows CIFS) or UDP-161 (SNMP).

```
sudo nmap -sP -PS22,135 192.168.1.1/24 #custom TCP SYN scan
sudo nmap -sP -PU161 192.168.1.1/24 #custom UDP scan
```